# $C^\infty$ Manifolds. Charts.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $ (M,\mathcal{O},A_{\infty})$ be a $C^\infty$-Differentiable dimension-d Manifold.

Recall that this setup means : $M$ is a set, $\mathcal{O}$ a topology, $A_{\infty}$ an atlas of charts "$x:M\to\mathbb{R}^d$", for which any two charts $x,y$ are $C^\infty$ compatible.

I have been told in a $C^\infty$ manifold chart maps are differentiable. Am I right in thinking this is true since $x\circ x^{-1}=\text{id}$, (the identity map $\text{id}:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$), which is clearly infinitely differentiable.

Also I could make this exact same statement about a $C^k$-differentiable manifold right?

Comment: If $\varphi_{\alpha} : U_{\alpha} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a chart, then *as a function*, it is said to be smooth if for every chart $\varphi_{\beta} : U_{\beta} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}\neq \varnothing$, the function $\varphi_{\alpha}\circ \varphi_{\beta}^{-1} : \varphi_{\beta}(U_{\alpha}\cap U_{\beta})\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth. But this condition is exactly saying that the atlas is compatible. One can restrict the regularity to a $C^{k,s}$ atlas and the proof is the same.

Comment: yeh this is what I thought. Strange question to ask anyway. @DIdier_ could you help, what are people referring to when they say smooth manifold ? do they mean $C^\infty$?

Comment: In most texts, smooth means $C^{\infty}$, although some authors refers to smooth for $C^1$: they usually states their own definition in an introductory part so the reader will not be confused